# Can you bypass a 403 code in Selenium WebDriver using cookies?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm accessing a `url` string via the `src` attribute of an `img` Html element using `WebDriver`. However, when i try to open a new window to that URL i get a `403 Unauthorized` access and i don't know how to overcome it. I've read many posts here on stackoverflow but the most promising solution i saw, was to specify a `User agent` preference in a `URLConnection`, but to no avail. Here's my code so far :

```
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();            
        String urlSelector = "body > div.overlay > div#cards"+cardID + " > div.one.card > img.core.load.bg.on";
        WebElement urlElem = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(urlSelector));
        String url = urlElem.getAttribute("src");
        driver.get(url);
```

**EDIT:**
I read on another post that i may need to pass certain cookies to the `URLConnection` in order to avoid the `403` response code and to authenticate myself. So i checked the cookies that are present when i am on the website (using the `WebDriver`) and the results are shown below:

[image: cookies_one]

[image: cookies_two]

However, if i open the same website on a normal browser (not using `WebDriver`) , i get some **extra** `imgur` cookies which are list below :

[image: cookies_three]
[image: cookies_four]

Imgur is what the site is using to display the images when i click on their links as far as i understand. I also decided to check the cookies on imgur after clicking on the image's link in a normal browser and i got 2 which seem to be related to a database(?) :

[image: cookies_five]

Is any of these cookies as far as you can tell used to authenticate me and is there a way to use those in my `URLConnection` to avoid the `403` response code?

P.S: Website in question is this [website](https://www.dbz.space/cards)

Comment: the site may be preventing deep-linking here which might have to do with the referrer... It's worth noting that opening an image in the browser will leave you with no DOM to manipulate... (Selenium won't be able to work with it...)  Why are you trying to navigate to the resource?

Comment: @pcalkins Hi and thanks for the answer. I want to download it actually

Comment: gotcha... well you've already downloaded it...  but not sure how to get to the cached resource through code.

Comment: well ive downloaded the url right? not the image itself? I've also tried another approach by opening the context menu on that image at that url via the web driver but i always need to click save in the system dialog that opens. Can i somehow remove and automate that system part?

Comment: The browser has downloaded it... it's on your hard drive wherever the browser stores its cache.

Comment: @pcalkins yup found the cache folder but i can't make anything of it. Any ideas? If i open the url in a normal browser it goes through no problem. But doing it through webdriver or `ImageIO.read();` throws a 403

Comment: one thing you might want to try is executing a javascript that returns the image file and then use Java to write that to your drive... or alternatively write (document.write) it into the page into a standard div/image tag and take a screenshot of that.  (similar to a "preload" script...)  The referrer in that case would be correct if that's what's preventing the URL load.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201121/discussion-between-stelios-papamichail-and-pcalkins).

Comment: can't do that but I may be able to work something out a bit later... I'll post an answer if I find a solution.

Comment: Alright, thanks either way, i'll also keep on looking

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try (haven't tested it yet):

```
 WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();            
 String urlSelector = "body > div.overlay > div#cards"+cardID + " > div.one.card > img.core.load.bg.on";
  WebElement urlElem = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(urlSelector));
  String url = urlElem.getAttribute("src");
  ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("img = document.createElement('img'); 
      img.src = '"+ url + "';  img.id='forscreenshot'; document.body.appendChild(img);");
         WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,5);
         WebElement element  = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.id('forscreenshot')));
         File screenshot = element.getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
```

Comment: I'm a bit lost with the `img = document.createElement()` string. Where does the string for it` end, where is the `img` object created in order to access properties/methods , what is the `img` instance you are using ?

Comment: it's just an <img...> tag.  It's appended to the body tag so it should show up at the bottom.  (Depending on the structure of the current page, you may want to append it    to another tag... and/or set z-order)